# how can I solve csrf verification failed

Tags: ajax, django, django-csrf

I'm trying to create form that uploads a zip file to the server. But everytime I click the submit I keep getting `CSRF verification failed` error. This is my html code:

```
<form method="POST" name="form-import-file" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept=".zip"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload file">
    </div>
</form>
<div class="url-csrf" data-csrf="{{ csrf_token }}"></div>
<div class="url-import-file" data-url-import-file="{% url 'intent:import_file' %}"></div>
```

In my .js code:

```
$("form[name='form-import-file']").submit(function(e) {
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    alert(formData);
    var json_data = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $('.url-csrf').attr('data-csrf'), 'file': formData };
    $.ajax({
        url: $('.url-import-file').attr('data-url-import-file'),
        type: "POST",
        data: json_data,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Did you try to add `{{ csrf_token }}` like this `<form method="POST" name="form-import-file" enctype="multipart/form-data">{{ csrf_token }}` and not outside from your form.

Comment: Yes but I keep getting the same error. Forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

`{% csrf_token %}` is hidden input field not a `value`

In Html

```
<div id="csrf_token">
    {% csrf_token %}
</div>
```

In js

```
let csrfToken = $("#csrf_token").val();
var json_data = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : csrfToken, 'file': formData };
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the cookie based CSRF provided by django doc?

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

Then add `'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : csrftoken,` in you json_data

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is probably the one described in Django documentation: [Cross Site Request Forgery protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#module-django.middleware.csrf)

If your `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS` and `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` settings are `False`, I suggest you create `init.js` file and always load it in your base html template. Include these two functions in this file:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
};
```

To include CSRF token in your ajax requests, you include it in request headers with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You can include this in `init.js` file you created earlier, if you wish, but it must be loaded after jQuery library.

If you have `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS` and `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` set to True, add `{% csrf_token %}` to your forms (or somewhere else in your HTML), read the token from there and include it in your ajax request, for example like this:

```
var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    },
    url: ...
    ...
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use [ensure_csrf_cookie](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie)
in the view that renders the page. Important, the decorator must be in the view that renders the page,
not in the view that receives the `post` request.

```py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie

@ensure_csrf_cookie
def get_the_page(request):
    return render(request, 'template.html')
```

Comment: are you sure about the import status?

Comment: nope, it was a copy and paste error, I've edited the response

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but I keep getting the same forbidden error.